# How to secure cookies across any domain?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

Is there any alternative ways to secure cookies access other then domains?

in my application i am setting cookie on 1 fix domain (cookie.xyz.com) and i need to track user on any domain, basically we are SaSS company and our client will put our js code on his website(s), then we set and get cookie on our one cookie.xyz.com because client can put our js on multiple domains. (right now i am using iframe and window messaging to get/set cookies on cookie.xyz.com)

So now in my case anybody can steal cookie  of end user using js and use that and he can himself became that end user.

So what could be solution this so only my code (running in context on any domain) can read and write cookie from particular domain (we do this because our client don't have one or fix domains).

Before downvote this question let me tell you.
I know its not possible, thats why i ask here to find possible or hacky solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a Cross Origin use case where you want to give liberty on your origin domain BUT you want to add control on it.

Both cases are complicated to coexist.

A solution is to add on your back end webservice a control on the origin of the request such as :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://origin.domain:port");
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

And update your JS Call to add credentials to true.

Comment: please read and go through my question again. i know these stuff.. people can still get cookies form that domain same way i am getting and setting using my js on x domain.. and on x domain i want to set/get cookies from cookies.xyz.com where x can be any domain..

Comment: origin.domain is not one domain.. it can be any domain...

thats why i can use this...

Comment: Please read my reply before saying it is wrong. You want to secure things BUT you want to open it for everyone. IT S NOT COMPATIBLE !

Comment: origin.domain is  not one domain that why i am using iframe thing and setting/setting cookies from iframe of cookie.xyz.com, then my js on origin domain commincation with iframe and get/set cookies

Comment: i know its hard, that why i am asking people that if its possible or not. or may be there could be other way then domains..

Comment: it is not hard. it is not compatible !

Comment: ok its not compatible, but there colud be same hacky solution people may knew it.. because then how other sass companies (who assume client can have multiple domains) work.